# Start Electron after Parcel.js started development server

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to improve my [Parcel.js](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) build but I'm not sure how to do it.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/AWolf81/electron-react-parcel-boilerplate).

## Build process to improve `yarn start`

At the moment, Electron starts in parallel with the build process and displays a blank page until parcel finished.

But I'd like to wait for first bundle before starting Electron.

## What I've tried

- Changed `npm-run-all` to run `dev` then `start:electron` sequentially but parcel is blocking the following thread, so Electron was not starting
- Spawn `start:electron` from build script (see `scripts/dev.js`) but app doesn't start correctly. I'll describe this in more details below. It would be great if it would work with-out that custom script but I'm not sure if that's possible
- Also tested the code mentioned [here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1458) or [here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/800) with the same result.

## Dev script

In the repo the scripts are 'commented' `in package.json`. Just change `commented_dev` and `commented_start` to dev & start to test my current version of the script.

The script is correctly running sequentially but Electron is unable to load from the server (see screenshot below)

I've also tried to run `start:electron` with `npm run` and `execSync` but that wasn't working. It seems like parcel is not correctly starting the dev server - maybe that's related to a configuration that's missing because the server starts correctly with the parcel command from CLI.
(`localhost:1234` is also not accessible from a web browser.)

Here is the script:

```
const Bundler = require("parcel-bundler");
const Path = require("path");
const { spawn, execSync, fork } = require("child_process");

// Entrypoint file location
const file = Path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.html");

console.log("file", file);

const options = {
  //outDir: './dist', // The out directory to put the build files in, defaults to dist
  //outFile: 'index.html', // The name of the outputFile
  publicUrl: "./" // The url to server on, defaults to dist
};

async function runBundle() {
  // Initializes a bundler using the entrypoint location and options provided
  const bundler = new Bundler(file, options);

  bundler.on("bundled", bundle => {
    // bundler contains all assets and bundles, see documentation for details
    // gets called once after first bundle
  });

// bundler.bundle(); // this is in the script but I would comment this

// Run the bundler, this returns the main bundle
// Use the events if you're using watch mode as this promise will only      trigger once and not for every rebuild 
 const bundle = bundler.serve().then(server => {
   console.log("server listen");
   spawn("yarn", ["start:electron"], {
     stdio: "inherit",
     shell: true
    });
  });
  await bundle;
}
runBundle();
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, I've found why the server wasn't starting correctly. After changing `const file = Path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.html");` to `const file = "./src/index.html"` it's working. So no need to join with `__dirname`.